# Google flight notifications

Tags: notifications, google-now

For some time now my phone notifies me every day about some flight status, which I'm not interested in. I looked in Google Now settings and can't find a way to disable it. There isn't even a card related to travel. Is there any way to turn it off? It's really annoying.

Comment: Maybe it's picking up from *Web and app activity*? Settings >app Settings and then Google *Personal info & privacy and then Activity controls*and 
Turn the switch on or off.

Comment: Do you have Google Allo installed and configured?

Comment: I don't have Allo. I found a flight I searched some time ago on my desktop and this seems to be it. Well, at least it's not a random plane, but still I don't wish to see it.

Comment: So, did turning off the web privacy fix?

Comment: I'll wait till tomorrow morning - that's always when I get the notification.

Comment: Nope, still getting the notifications.